# Is it practical to dynamically normalize a table?

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-normalization

Let's say my database tracks bird sightings (Note: I'm really scraping the bottom of the barrel for examples).

The fields are:

```
sighting_id | common_name | park_name | location | time | etc....
```

Although I'm assuming that a park will always be in the same location, the website is like a spreadsheet. The user enters `park_name` and `location` for every entry. Also please note that my actual schema has other fields that are dependent on the analogous "park name" as well (e.g. state).

I do not have a way for the user to predefine parks, so I can't know them ahead of time. Should I even attempt to dynamically normalize this data? For example, should my program automatically populate a `parks` table, replacing the park_name and location column in the bird sighting table with a `park_id`?

I'm worried about performance, mostly. Listing every sighting would require a join to populate park and location. Also, dynamically managing this would almost certainty require more resources than it would save. I would probably need a Cron job to eliminate orphaned Parks, since they may be referenced in multiple sightings.

Comment: This "problem" seems to grow out of nowhere... there should (likely) be a `parks` table. Even if two parks (say in different states) have the same name, they are *two different parks* (as noted) and this should be captured. **Start with a good model -- and don't worry about performance until it is analyzed and determined to be an issue**. It's easier to improve performance than fix bad data and a "good model" will be just as fast -- if not faster -- here.

Comment: I don't care about parks being the same: this data will only be displayed; not acted on. My actual problem (this was just supposed to be an analogy, but I'm realizing that it wasn't very good) deals with name, sex, and university columns. I don't necessarily care if two people have the same name, sex, etc. I'm just wondering if it is worth it to not duplicate this data.

Comment: Unless there is a proven test case, it is not worth it. Saving the handful of records (where all the fields happen to align) will gain nothing. In fact, it will be much harder to maintain -- a person's name (and gender) can change *independent* from other people (and are thus separate entities).

Comment: That is very true. If a name (or gender) is changed, it's a mad dash to find all names that are actually used so I can delete the orphaned ones.

Comment: Please note that I have clarified my original question resulting in this spinoff question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325052/is-normalization-required-in-this-case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on a bit on your usage.  The normalized approach (park is a table) will make the following queries easier:

- How many bird sightings have there been for each park
- At which park are you most likely to see bird XYZ
- There are probably quite a few more queries like this

But yes, you do run into some sticky issues.  The pattern "if park XYZ doesn't exist then insert it into the parks table" suffers from a race condition that you'll have to deal with.

Now, how about some arguments against normalization here...  Most customer databases probably store my street address as "123 Foo Street", without dynamically normalizing the street name (we could have a street table and put "Foo Street" there, then reference it from other tables.  Why do I bring this up, well to show that even the guys who hate any repeated data will probably acknowledge that there is some line you don't necessarily have to cross.

Another silly example would be that we might share last names.  Do we really need a table for unique last names and then foreign key to it from other tables?  There might be some applications where this is helpful but for 99% of application out there, this goes too far.  It's just more work and less performant for little to no gain.

So I'd consider how I want to be able to query data back out of the table.  Honestly in this case I'd probably do a separate table for parks.  But in other cases I've chosen not to.

That's my two cents, one cent after taxes.

Comment: @Matthew: Thank you for your insights :). My actual problem (like I said, this one is just an analogy) is closer to your "last name" table example. The fields I am dealing with are name, sex, and university.

Comment: Let's see.  Name could be stored in a separate table, but that's lame.  So let' say no dynamic normalization on that.  Gender I'd do an enum-like column (values 1,2).  For style reasons avoid having Gender be a bool.  Now the Unversity I'd be tempted to normalize but again it depends on how you'll do queries.

Comment: I'll be searching for rows based on the University. I would suppose that that operation would be even less efficient if I had to join on a Universities table.

Comment: If you do normalize the university you'll have to create university rows "just-in-time" as users enter universities that you don't already have.  This is feasible but dealing with the race condition depends on some deployment conditions.  Will there be just one app involved?  If so you can choose from a number of traditional synchronization primitives.  If, on the other hand there could be multiple apps involved, then you'll have to use a cross-app synchronization primitive (not so much fun).

Comment: It will be multi-user. I'm using PHP and Zend Framework. But, it will just be one application.

Comment: I don't think that join (searching on rows based on University) will hurt you much.  You'll end up putting an index on the foreign key (on the student table) and it'll run pretty quickly.

Comment: Oh, the one app thing will be in your favor.  I'm not familiar with PHP but I'm sure there are some easy ways to create the locking you need.  You may be able to achieve the same effect using MySQL itself but I'm not very familiar with MySQL either.  Don't hold it against me but I'm more a C#/MSSQL guy :)

Comment: I'm stuck at a crossroads here. On one hand, trying to manage a Students table will be a pain, but on the other, I know that it will save a lot of space.

Comment: Adding students that I've never seen before to my database will be fairly painless. Cleaning up the orphans would have to run periodically with a Cron job. Locking isn't necessary; MySQL manages all that.

Comment: I believe that application-layer locking will be necessary for the pattern "If University XYZ doesn't already exist, create a record for University XYZ".  It's a classic problem that requires a lock because otherwise you run the risk that you'll end up with two records for the same university (due to timing).

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. MySQL can do table and row-level locking, so I'll have to build that into my queries. So, would you recommend that I create a Student's table? Like you said, the sex field wouldn't be worth normalizing since its one bit. Not sure about name or university.

Comment: Well I'm not entirely understanding your needs.  But it sounds like you *need* a student table.  The first name column and last name column would be strings (not foreign keys), the gender would be an int, and then the university would be a foreign key to a university table.  Again, not sure I understand your needs but from what you've said I think this is what you want.

Comment: I agree. It will be more work but it will save precious space. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, don't get me wrong - I'm not so much concerned about space as I am that some of your queries will be easy with the normalized relationship between student and university.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: There won't be a relationship between Student and University. Some entity has the columns Student, Sex, and University. Student, Sex, and University relate to each other, but are not explicitly defined by the user.

Answer (score 2):

My two cents on the original "parks" example (as opposed to the OP's *actual* problem):

The decisive argument against trying to automatically normalize the park and location columns is **usability**: when data is presented to the user in an editable spreadsheet-like format, they will naturally assume that each row can be *independently* edited, so it's deceptive (and likely to lead ultimately to confusion) if some columns such as "location" are actually associated with the park, rather than the row.

A typical pattern for handling this sort of situation is to only prompt the user for park's details and create a row in the "parks" table when a *new* park is entered. For example, if the park column contains a drop-down box, then the last option could be "add new park". Alternatively, add a new park when the user enters an unrecognized park name -- but still make it clear to the user that a new park is being created.

Comment: The idea would be that the user would have no clue that the Parks were actually being consolidated behind the scenes, with distinct ones being placed into their own table.